# python function try & except

Tags: python, function

I wonder what am i missing in my very simple function

I want to create a simple function which will take as argument other function and will try to run it. If it can't proceed then it should go to except statement.

```
def if_not_found(formula):
    try:
        return formula
    except:
        print('nothing')

text1 = if_not_found(element.find('span', {'class': 'listitem123'}).text.split()[0].replace('kd', ''))
print(text1)
```

Why I receive below? Why it didn't print 'nothing'?

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Comment: Please read [mcve] for asking a good question!

Comment: You're not passing *a function* into `if_not_found`, you're running your function outside of it and are only passing its return value into `if_not_found` (which then does absolutely nothing with it).

Answer (score 0):

Probably the error is on the parser, the statement `element.find('span', {'class': 'listitem123'})` is returning None. Besides that, you are calling the replace method, so you are not passing a function as an argument to `if_not_found`, you are passing the result of the replace method.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo. `element.find("span", {"class": "listitem123"})` was not found, so it returned `None`. `.text` is not an attribute of `None`.

Maybe something like this would suit your situation better?

```py
def found_or_none(element):
    found = element.find("span", {"class": "listitem123"})
    if found:
        return found.text.split()[0].replace("kd", "")
    else:
        return None

text1 = found_or_none(element)
if text1:
    print(text1)
else:
    print("Element not found")
```